# Condition of two hyperbolas do not intersect

Tags: geometry

Given two hyperbolas h1(with foci and center) and h2(with foci and center), In what condition these hyperbolas will not intersect to each other?. I can get the condition when h1 and h2 are standard hyperbola (parallel to axis and the center is the origin). I want to find the condition when both of them are not standard hyperbola. Thanks

Comment: I think you ask a too general question. You should for example restrict your attention to equilateral hyperbolas and take one of them as the standard equilateral hyperbola with equation $xy=1$ and the other one as a rotated + translated image of the first one. Besides, do you know the focal definition $|MF-MF'| \ = \ $constant of a hyperbola ?

Comment: @JeanMarie. Thanks and apologize for unclear question. This question is for equilateral hyperbola. I know that constant property of hyperbola

Answer (score 2):

Let $x^2-y^2=1$ be the first hyperbola.

- Re-scaling
  $$x^2-y^2=c^2 \tag{$c^2 \ne 1$}$$
- Conjugate
  $$y^2-x^2=c^2$$
- Translation
  \begin{align*}
    (x-h)^2-(y-k)^2 &= 1 \\
    2(ky-hx)+h^2-k^2 &= 0 \\
    x &= \frac{h^2-k^2+2ky}{2h} \\
    (h^2-k^2+2ky)^2-4h^2 y^2 &= 4h^2 \\
    4(h^2-k^2)y^2-4k(h^2-k^2)y+4h^2-(h^2-k^2)^2 &= 0 \\
    \Delta & < 0 \\
    k^2(h^2-k^2)^2-(h^2-k^2)[4h^2-(h^2-k^2)^2] & < 0 \\
    h^2(h^2-k^2)(h^2-k^2-4) &< 0 \\
  \end{align*}

$$\fbox{$0<h^2-k^2<4$}$$

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I still don't get the second line (before x=......). Where are x^2 and y^2 go, they suddenly disappear.

Comment: Equating $x^2-y^2=(x-h)^2-(y-k)^2=1$, all quadratic terms have gone.  Then substitute either back into either hyperbola.

Comment: [+1] Good treatment of the condition $0<h^2-k^2<4$ with a nice drawing giving a geometrical understanding. It remains to show that, if there is a rotation, whatever the translation, there are necessarily intersection points. I think I have a proof now. I will write it in the coming hours.

Comment: In general, if conic $ax^2+bxy+cy^2=1$ is translated by $(h,k)$ such that they don't intersect, then $$(b^2-4ac)(ah^2+bhk+ck^2)(ah^2+bhk+ck^2-4)<0$$

Comment: In general hyperbola equation ax^2+bxy+cy^2=1. Are a, b and c here similar with a,b,c in standard hyperbola equation x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 = 1, where a^2+b^2 = c^2? Thanks

Comment: No, it's general form for central conics.  Some texts may write it in quadratic form: $$\begin{pmatrix} x & y \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a & \frac{b}{2} \\ \frac{b}{2} & c \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

use the [answer of this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2143732/hyperbola-equation-not-parallel-to-axis) to get two equations, set them inequal to each other, then that is your condition, swap them back to focal model.

PS: it might be easier to answer in polar or bipolar coordinates, as they seem more suitable for parabola solving problems

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider the reference equilateral hyperbola with equation $xy=1$ (see blue curve on graphics below). Any rectangular hyperbola can be obtained from the reference with a rotation (angle $\theta$) followed by a translation (vector $\binom{a}{b}$). One should obtain the following result :

- if $\theta\neq0$, there are intersection points.
- If $\theta=0$, the only translations that give no intersection point are with vector $k\binom{1}{1}$ for $-2<k<2$ 
  (see the example of the magenta curve).

I thought I have a proof but it is not the case.

[image]

Comment: I have withdrawn the major part of my "proof" (which had a flaw). and modied the graphics.